# Add Custom expect Matcher type definition, when running cucumber-js with ts-node/esm

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cucumberjs

I have a cucumber-js step-definition that uses a custom-matcher that I've written and added to expect using `expect.extends(...)`, which works as expected when I use a `@ts-ignore` flag, but when removed the incorrect typings are causing compilation errors.

We are importing expect straight from the `expect` node module which types `expect` as so:

```js
export declare type Expect = {
  <T = unknown>(actual: T): Matchers<void> &
    Inverse<Matchers<void>> &
    PromiseMatchers;
} & BaseExpect &
  AsymmetricMatchers &
  Inverse<Omit<AsymmetricMatchers, 'any' | 'anything'>>;

declare const expect_2: Expect;
export default expect_2;
export {expect_2 as expect};
```

I have an async custom-matcher here:

file: './feature-tests/support/custom-matchers.ts'

```js
import type { MatcherFunction } from 'expect';

import { inTimeoutRace } from './utils/in-timeout-race';

export const toWaitForCallWith: MatcherFunction<[timeout: number, target: any]> = async function (
    dataSource: any,
    timeout: number,
    ...expected: Array<any>
) {
    let cancel = false;
    let pass = false;
    let currentTimeout: NodeJS.Timeout;
    let errMessage: string;

    const findCall = (): Promise<boolean> => {
        const retryDelay = 1000;
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const tryFindCall = () => {
                if (dataSource.mock.calls.some((call: any) => this.equals(expected, call))) {
                    resolve(true);
                }

                if (!cancel) {
                    currentTimeout = setTimeout(tryFindCall, retryDelay);
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(currentTimeout);
                }
            };

            tryFindCall();
        });
    };

    try {
        pass = await inTimeoutRace<boolean>(findCall(), timeout);
    } catch (e) {
        cancel = true;
        errMessage = `${e.message}\n\tdataSource: ${dataSource.constructor.name}, did not contain matched call after ${timeout}ms`;
    }

    return {
        message: () => errMessage,
        pass,
    };
};
```

In the hooks.ts file I'm adding this declaration and am adding the function to `expect.extend()`

```js
declare global {
    namespace expect {
        interface Matchers<R> {
            toWaitForCallWith(timeout: number, target: any): R;
        }
        interface AsymmetricMatchers {
            toWaitForCallWith(timeout: number, target: any): void;
        }
    }
}

expect.extend({
    toWaitForCallWith,
});
```

In the step definition file I'm using the matcher like so:

```js
await expect(dataSource).toWaitForCallWith(
    15000,
    expect.objectContaining({
        body: expect.objectContaining({
            msgs: expect.arrayContaining([
                expect.objectContaining({
                    n: expect.stringMatching(eventName),
                }),
            ]),
        }),
    })
);
```

and the associated error message I get is:

```
Property 'toWaitForCallWith' does not exist on type 'Matchers<void> & Inverse<Matchers<void>> & PromiseMatchers'.ts(2339)
```

I'm expecting that the typings will work as expected. Without a `@ts-ignore` tag on the line above the use of the custom-matcher, ts-node receives a compilation error.